# check which anchor button opened the pop up page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have

`<a class="zipbutton" onclick="window.open('www.site.com/zipfinder/','popupwindow'...>`.

There are 2 input fields in my home page. *From Zip code* and *To Zip code*. Beside them are the anchor buttons that opens a page which the user can find zip code based on city and state then post the zip code to the corresponding text field. What I did was, I created 2 separate pages for each anchor button. Is there any way to combine them into one pop up window?

Here is the sample code for one of the **pop up page**:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function post_value(){
        window.opener.document.getElementById("FromZip").value = document.getElementById("cityBox").value;
        self.close();
        }
</script>
```

and

```
    function post_value(){
            window.opener.document.getElementById("ToZip").value = document.getElementById("cityBox").value;
            self.close();
        }
```

Comment: try jquery dialog-modal

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the -
1) event.srcElement in Internet Explorer 
2) event.target in most other browsers.

This will give the src element from where the click event originated in your case the anchor element.Put a filter on the element id and use only one popup.

Click [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventtargetsrcelement.htm) for more information.

Sample Code:-

```
 <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function post_value(event){
if(event.target!=null)
{
  var target=event.target.id;//This is the id of the element which triggered the event.
}
    window.opener.document.getElementById("FromZip").value = document.getElementById("cityBox").value;
    self.close();
}
```

Comment: var target will hold the value of the pop up page's submit button ( the button that will post the zip to the parent page). But i want to get the ID of the button that opened the pop up page in the first place.

Comment: I was giving just an example to show how you could bind a similar function to the click event of your anchor element while opening the pop up page,store it in a hidden variable and access it while submitting the page. e.g. while opening the popup $('#hdnBtnID')=event.target.id. Now access the same when executing post_value()

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example to do this. I'm using JQuery to do this.

Html form

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="FromZip" name="FromZip">
<a href="#" class="button_open_Fromzipcode">Zip code</a>
<br>
<input type="text" id="ToZip" name="FromZip">
<a href="#" class="button_open_Tozipcode">Zip code</a>

</form>

<div id="zipcodes">
<a href="#" class="button_close_zipcode">Close</a>
<br>

<!--LOAD YOUR ZIP CODES HERE-->

<!--For Example-->
<a href="#" class="zipcode">0001</a><br>
<a href="#" class="zipcode">0002</a><br>
<a href="#" class="zipcode">0003</a><br>
<a href="#" class="zipcode">0004</a><br>
<a href="#" class="zipcode">0005</a><br>
<a href="#" class="zipcode">0006</a><br>
<a href="#" class="zipcode">0007</a>

</div>
```

Style for zipcodes container

```
<style type="text/css">
#zipcodes
{   
    display: none;
    color:#000;
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: left;
    min-height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #000;
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    top:40%;
    left:40%;
    padding: 16px;
    z-index:1000;

}
</style>
```

Here is the Jquery script. 
Make sure add the jquery library within the head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>



   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var zipbox;

//Open zipcode container
    $(".button_open_Fromzipcode").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#zipcodes").css("display","block");
        zipbox="FromZip";//flag the return textbox
    });

//Open zipcode container
    $(".button_open_Tozipcode").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#zipcodes").css("display","block");
        zipbox="ToZip";//flag the return textbox
    });

  //Close zipcode container
    $(".button_close_zipcode").click(function(){
        $("#zipcodes").css("display","none");
    });



    $(".zipcode").click(function(){
        $("#"+zipbox).val($(this).text());//Set selected zipcode to Textbox
        $("#zipcodes").css("display","none");//Close zipcode container
    });

    });
    </script>
```